# React Material UI: this.props undefined when using withStyles and React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

In the Parent Component, this.props exists and can find { classes } just fine. However, in the Child Component, this.props is undefined and { classes } cannot be found. Both are wrapped in a HOC, but the Child Component is rendered via React Router. Relevant code below, please let me know if you need any more context:

Parent:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
...
import styles from "../../assets/ParentPage/styles";
import theme from "../../assets/theme";
import LandingPageCard from './ParentPageCard';
import { Grid, ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core";
import { ChildComponent } from "../../components/NRLMSIS/MsisForm";

import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";

export class ParentPage extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Router>
            <Grid
              container
              spacing={4}
              className={classes.gridContainer}
              justify="center"
            >
              <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
                <Link to="/child">
                  <LandingPageCard />
                </Link>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>

            <Switch>
              <Route path="/child" component={ChildComponent} />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
      </ThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

Child:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
...
import theme from "../../assets/theme";
import styles from "../../assets/ChildCompnent/styles";

export class ChildCompnent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

    render() {
      const { classes } = this.props;
      console.log("PROPS: ", this.props); // this.props == undefined
      return (
        <Grid container component="main" className={classes.root}>
          <CssBaseline/>
        </Grid>
      );
    }
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(ChildCompnent);
```

Comment: This is not ChildComponent but it will trigger another rendering when the child path will match so its just render another component. So if you really wants to do it you can do something like that, <Route path='/child' component={(props) => < ChildComponent {...props} />} />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you did export default and the import is with `{}`, this is works because you added export to the class, but you have another export (default) with the styles... do:

```
import  ChildComponent from "../../components/NRLMSIS/MsisForm";
```